# Reboot Ubuntu system after editing config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

I edited my Ubuntu config file using the command `vi`, then I restarted the system by typing `reboot` but after it has rebooted the config file reverts back to how it was! Any ideas please ?

Here is what i type in the terminal :

```
 vi /temp/m1.conf
i
here is the new command
escpe button
:wq
reboot
```

Comment: No permanent configuration would be held in a temporary directory: you edited the wrong file - master configuration files are in `/etc/`. I have no idea what configuration file you want to change (there is not normally a `/temp/` in Linux/Unix, nor is there `m1.conf` in `/etc/` in later (16.04) versions of Linux, unless it belongs to a subsystem which is not loaded by default. Please clarify your question.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i write a random directory for my personal reasons